# Unable to access table with "/" in table name in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

You can create a table with `/` in its name, but you can't find or access it in cnosdb:

```
public ❯ create table "a/b"(id bigint);
Query took 0.009 seconds.
public ❯ show tables;
Query took 0.022 seconds.
public ❯ insert "a/b" values(now(), 1);
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: Table not found, tenant: cnosdb db: public, table: a/b"}
```