"show table" cannot display the table
I created a table, but "show table" does not display it.
public ❯ \d
Query took 0.007 seconds.
public ❯ create table "tb/001"(f1 bigint, tags(t1));
Query took 0.005 seconds.
public ❯ \d
Query took 0.006 seconds.
public ❯ show tables;
Query took 0.006 seconds.

Why can't this table be displayed?Does anyone know how to solve this?

is there a specific reason you are adding /001 in the name of the table?

This was previously reported at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77917380/unable-to-access-table-with-in-table-name-in-cnosdb .  It may be a product bug.
